# Strange box around the slider with Wordpress slider plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Working on a clients site which they seem to have changed some code by accident. The slider content now seems to have a strange boxed border around it ! You can see this on www.happyorganic.org

I have checked the CSS which has been applied to it but there seems to be no border on it. The slider is created with the plugin for WP called wordpress slider plugin.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The border is applied from this class name ".ssp_no_chrome_slider_default" rule is > box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #888888; inside flexslider.css solution you need to write an override class to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` in `.flexslider` 
and remove `box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;` in `.ssp_no_chrome_slider_default`